# jQuery: problem with dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog

i'm having 2 dialogs in my web - when setting their property `autoOpen:true`
they both show.
but when setting `autoOpen:false` (and open them manually) - only one dialog opens :(
with the other one, nothing happens at all (no error in firebug). any idea what it could be?
it can't be the dialog content, as i defined just some simple debug text.

---

```
div.dialog({ 
   autoOpen:false, 
   bgiframe: false, 
   resizable: true, 
   width:wi, 
   minHeight:0, 
   height:he, 
   modal: true, 
   title: div.attr("caption"), 
   overlay: { backgroundColor: '#ffffff', opacity: 0.8 } 
});
```

Comment: please include a concise piece of code that shows your problem.

Comment: here's my code for both dialogs
(sorry i thought it might be a known bug)

 div.dialog({
  autoOpen:false,
  bgiframe: false,
  resizable: true,
  width:wi,
  minHeight:0,
  height:he,
  modal: true,
  title: div.attr("caption"),
  overlay: {
   backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
   opacity: 0.8
   }
 });

Comment: we still need more code... what's being clicked, what is "div" etc

Comment: I have a gut feeling there may be two DIV elements with the same id. Just one of those wild ass guesses based on too little information.

Comment: @peter i had that feeling too, hence the request for more code :)

Answer (score 1):

div is probably not the right identifier for jQuery.

Change `div.dialog(...)` to `$("#mydialog").dialog(...)`

where the div containing the dialog is:

```
<div id="mydialog">put dialog content here.</div>
```

Comment: tempted to -1. If the div variable would be the problem, his code wouldn't work at all. I am almost sure that div is some variable which holds a jQuery object enclosing his DOM div element